# React native + firebase upload current uid to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to upload the current uid to the database into the object as well.
Here is the database structure:

```
/users
    /${currentUser.uid}
         /ads
            /firebaseobj
               -title
               -desc
               -subject
               -currentUser.uid  // I want this to show the same 
                // value as "${currentUser.uid}"
```

and here is the code that upload to the database:

```
 export const adCreate = ({ title, desc, subject, ??????? }) 
 => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
   firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currentUser.uid}/ads`)
    .push({ title,  desc, subject, currentuser.uid })
    .then(() => {
   dispatch({ type: RESET_AD });
  });
 };
};
```

Im not sure how i can declare the uid as a string so that I can put it into the object with the other strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push objects as a `key value` pair.

Since your objects are already destructured here `({ title, desc, subject})`

```
.push({ title,  desc, subject, currentUserId: currentuser.uid })
```